# Images product nullpointer when project built with gradle - Java

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

See the bottom for a TL;DR.

Hi,
So I thought this would be a pretty basic thing to do but it's giving me a headache :(

I'm writing a JavaFX application with some images. I'm using gradle to build the project.
My structure is like this:

```
src
- main
-- java
--- view
---- sections
----- WelcomeSection.java
-- resources
--- logo.png

- tests
--java
--resources
```

Having followed the gradle package structure, in WelcomeSection.java I have the following snippet of code (remember it's a JavaFX application):

```
Image logo = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../../../resources/logo.png"));
ImageView logoImageView = new ImageView(logo);
```

... which works beautifully when I compile and run with Eclipse.

When I try to run build through gradle, it produces the jar file. Upon running the jar file, I get the following runtime exception:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at main.java.view.sections.WelcomeSection.logoLabel(WelcomeSection.java:83)
        at main.java.view.sections.WelcomeSection.setupTopBar(WelcomeSection.java:73)
        at main.java.view.sections.WelcomeSection.setup(WelcomeSection.java:61)
        at main.java.view.sections.WelcomeSection.<init>(WelcomeSection.java:52)
        at main.java.view.MainView.setupWelcomeSection(MainView.java:27)
        at main.java.view.MainView.setup(MainView.java:37)
        at main.java.view.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:23)
        at main.java.Main.start(Main.java:26)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

...which clearly has something to do with the image paths. When I remove images, it works fine when building with gradle.

TL;DR: How do I correctly reference images within the Javafx application so that they work both in Eclipse and **more importantly when building with gradle**? I tried changing the path in the Java code for src/main/resources/logo.png but this still doesn't work with gradle nor when I run in Eclipse.

Comment: Have you tried `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/logo.png")` ?

Comment: Strike that, this worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is directly under `src/main/resources` it means that it is at the **root level** of your classpath so it should be `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/logo.png")` as next:

```
Image logo = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/logo.png"));
ImageView logoImageView = new ImageView(logo);
```

However please note that the constructor `Image(String url)` according to the format of the `url` can try to get the image from the context `ClassLoader` so you should be able to get the same result simply with:

```
Image logo = new Image("/logo.png");
ImageView logoImageView = new ImageView(logo);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should not reference resources folder in your code! `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, etc are not part of java project hierarchy but are part of gradle/maven architecture and related to how they handle code and resources internally.

This is one way you can structure your project hierarchy: just create the same hierarchy as your `src/main/java/<path>/WelcomeSection.java` in `src/main/resources/<path>/` and put `logo.png` there. You can think that gradle will merge these two and you'll gonna have `WelcomeSection.java` and `logo.png` in the same directory.

```
 src
- main
-- java
--- view
---- sections
----- WelcomeSection.java
-- resources
---view
----sections
-----logo.png
```

and in java code:

```
Image logo = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("logo.png"));
```

Comment: So I followed this advice, adjusted the folders accordingly and built with gradle. Still got the same exception :(

Comment: Is your structure like this: `src/main/java/view/sections/WelcomeSection.java` and `src/main/resources/view/sections/logo.png`.  ?

Comment: Precisely like that. I also changed the source to be what you suggested.

Comment: please use `WelcomeSection.class.getResourceAsStream(...)` instead of `getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)` and let me know if that solves the problem

Comment: Changed it but to no avail :((